# Starting a GUI before the login window on raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, service, debian, raspberry-pi4

I Have a raspberry pi 4B running using Debian GNU/Linux 12. I created an executable file as GUI.
I want to start this GUI before the login window appear and when ever the user close it the login appear again.
I just created a service for this prepuce but still getting error.
the GUI is starting after the login is attempt .
this is my service :

```
[Unit]
Description=My PyInstaller Executable
Before=graphical.target
After=lightdm.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30 # Add a delay to ensure X server is fully initialized
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /home/pi/Desktop/NewMain
User=pi
Group=pi
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

and this is the error:

```
Dec 06 07:00:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting My PyInstaller Executable...
Dec 06 07:01:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started My PyInstaller Executable.
Dec 06 07:01:58 raspberrypi NewMain[855]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyTraceback (most recent call last):
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi NewMain[855]: File "NewMain.py", line 326, in <module>
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi NewMain[855]: File "NewMain.py", line 308, in main
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi NewMain[855]: File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi NewMain[855]: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi NewMain[855]: [855] Failed to execute script 'NewMain' due to unhandled exception!
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: myservice.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 06 07:01:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: myservice.service: Consumed 1.550s CPU time.
Dec 06 07:02:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: myservice.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```